# Python TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType

Tags: python, function

I am newbee trying to learn python using LPTH. I trying to do exercise 21 in a different way. Instead of putting the values in the variable, I am asking the user to put the value.

```
def add(a,b):
    print "Add %d and %d." %(a,b)
    print a+b

def substract (a,b):
    print "Substract %d from %d." %(a,b)
    print a-b

def multiply (a,b):
    print "Multiply %d*%d." %(a,b)
    print a*b

def divide (a,b):
    print "Dividing %d and %d." %(a,b)
    print a/b

total_age_of_the_class = add(int(raw_input(">")) , int(raw_input(">")))
#height_difference = substract (int(raw_input("Ram's height:"), int(raw_input("Shyam's height:"))))
height = substract (78,4)
weight = multiply (90,2)
iq = divide (100,2)

print "Age:%d, height:%d, weight:%d, iq:%d" %(total_age_of_the_class, height, weight, iq)
```

For some reason it throws an error when the code run the last line of the code.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be *returning* the results from your functions, not printing them:

```
def substract (a,b):
    print "Substract %d from %d." %(a,b)
    return a-b

def multiply (a,b):
    print "Multiply %d*%d." %(a,b)
    return a*b

def divide (a,b):
    print "Dividing %d and %d." %(a,b)
    return a/b
```

Without a [return statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt), Python functions always return the default value of `None`.  This means that when you get to here:

```
height = substract (78,4)
weight = multiply (90,2)
iq = divide (100,2)
```

`height`, `weight`, and `iq` will all be assigned to `None`, which causes the string formatting operation to fail with your error.